# Planes in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a question, say I have two linearly independent vectors, then would there be only one plane in R3 containing these two vectors?

Comment: Is in ${\Bbb{R}}^3$ where all is happening?

Comment: Yes,but please also tell me what will happen to other dimensions.

Comment: By plane, do you mean "2-dimensional subspace" or "proper subspace"? I ask because the term "hyperplane" is often used to describe the situation where you have a proper subspace of a vector space, that is, a vector subspace with strictly smaller dimension than its given superspace, and I want to make sure you actually mean "plane" in the classical sense of "2-dimensional flat object", without speculating as to your intent.

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clear, by plane I mean plane in R3

Comment: Okay, then the remark at the last paragraph of my answer is what you're looking for. To summarize, the answer is yes by definition, and I apologize for making things more complicated than they needed to be.

Comment: plane also is a 2-dimensional vector subspace plus a translation by a fixed vector $p\in{\Bbb{R}}^n$

Comment: @janmarqz That is a good point. If you feel like editing my answer to include the generalization to affine-but-not-necessarily-linear subspaces then I wouldn't object, but I'm too lazy to do so myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "plane". If you mean "2-dimensional subspace" then yes, by definition. (If you're interested in what happens when you generalize to hyperplanes and hence any proper subspaces then it depends:

1. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the result is no.
2. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, the answer is yes.
3. In $\mathbb{R}^4$, and higher, the answer is no.

*Proof of 1*: Calling the vectors $v, w$, we have $\mathbb{R}^2 = span(v,w)$, so no proper subspace contains the vectors.

*Sketch of proof of 2*: Let two proper subspaces contain $v, w$ and show they are equal. This is not hard to do, let me know if you need advice on carrying out the proof. It starts by pointing out that the subspace has to be of dimension 2 to be both proper and contain $v,w$.

*Sketch of proof of 3*: There are infinitely many vectors $z$ such that $\{v,w,z\}$ is linearly independent, and this is a proper subspace in every case.)

*But, to reiterate*: Since "plane" means for you a 2-dimensional subspace, then there is only one "plane" containing a given set of 2 linearly independent vectors, and this is because the plane containing 2 linearly independent vectors would be in this case defined as their span, i.e. the set of all their linear combinations, which is unique.

Comment: So far as I know it is standard in linear algebra for "plane" to mean "two-dimensional subspace".

Comment: So far as I know as well, but I didn't want to speculate that "hyperplane" was not meant without clarification.